# CLion NMake Error; Return Code: 0xffffffff

Tags: c++, clion, nmake

I'm new to working with CLion and the first thing on the start of my first project was an error I can't solve of course.
Here's the error I've been getting:
[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aPkE.png)

Sorry for the german, it says: 'unresolved external symbol' on the top errors and 'return code '0x2' ' on the lower ones.

The following shows my code, even though I really don't think it has anything to do with it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow*, int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 6);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "GameLabIII", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone knows anything about how to solve this, help would be very much appreciated, I don't have any ideas left how to solve this.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please post your code directly, instead of posting a screenshot of your code

Comment: These linker errors mean you forgot to link against the proper libraries. Which means something is wrong with your build setup

Comment: @UnholySheep Ah I see! Is there any way to find out what exactly is wrong or what I have to do to fix it? Sorry I am really new to this.

Comment: You need to link to the glad and glfw libraries